# How can I make the function keep going

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I building a program and have an execute button. I want to make that if it is the first time you use the program you need to login. if not then you don't need to because the login credentials are already saved. Here is my code. Right now it doesn't keep going with the rest of the execute function.

The loginSaver is an get and set method which sets the logincontinue to true in loginform.

IB-Form:

```
internal void ExecBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Username != "" || Password != "")
        {
            Username = Properties.Settings.Default.UserName.ToString();
            Password = Properties.Settings.Default.UserPass.ToString();
        }
        else if (loginForm.LoginSaver == true)
        {
            Username = loginForm.LoginUserName;
            Password = loginForm.LoginPassword;
        }
        else if (Username == "" || Password == "")
        {
            loginForm.Show();
            return;
        }
        
        

        if (ServerComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
                ServerComboBox.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                MessageBox.Show("Du måste välja en kund!");

                return;
        }
```

LoginForm:

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IB_Ärende IBForm = new IB_Ärende();
            if (UserNameTxt.Text == "" || PasswordTxt.Text == "")
            {
                UserNameTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                PasswordTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                UserNameTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                PasswordTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Du måste ange ett användarnamn och Lösenord!");
            }

            if (CheckBoxSave.Checked == true)
            {
                    IsServerConnected();
                    if (testingConnection == true)
                    {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = UserNameTxt.Text;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.UserPass = PasswordTxt.Text;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        //loginContinue = true;
                        this.Hide();
                        UserNameTxt.Text = "";
                        PasswordTxt.Text = "";

                        //IBForm.ExecBtn_Click(sender, e);
                    }
                    else if (testingConnection == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Fel användarnamn eller lösenord");
                        UserNameTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                        PasswordTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                        UserNameTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        PasswordTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        return;
                    }
                
            }
            else if (CheckBoxSave.Checked == false)
            {
                IsServerConnected();
                if (testingConnection == true)
                {
                    userName = UserNameTxt.Text;
                    passWord = PasswordTxt.Text;

                    loginchecker = true;
                    loginContinue = true;
                    this.Hide();
                    //IBForm.ExecBtn_Click(sender, e);
                    UserNameTxt.Text = "";
                    PasswordTxt.Text = "";
                }
                else if (testingConnection == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fel användarnamn eller lösenord");
                    UserNameTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                    PasswordTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                    UserNameTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    PasswordTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    return;
                                                                          
                }

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Du måste logga in för att kunna fortsätta!");
            }
            
        }
```

Thanks for helping...

Comment: save the username and password externally (File, DataBase) and then the program starts you can check if the username and password already exits there

Comment: Look up the difference between Show() and ShowDialog()

Comment: The problem is that im using this against a database but i cant use it there.. i need to use this way.. Can Show() and showdialog() be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want to block current function and wait for LoginForm to close use ShowDialog() instead of Show(). This way after closing login form you have access to Login/Password:

```
loginForm.ShowDialog();
Username = loginForm.LoginUserName;
Password = loginForm.LoginPassword;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) 
{
    return;
}
```

2.I suggest using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for checking if login/password is provided.

3.Instead of `if (CheckBoxSave.Checked == true)` you can write `if (CheckBoxSave.Checked)`

4.If you have condition that evaluates to True/False e.g. `if (CheckBoxSave.Checked == true)` in else do not use another `if` like `else if (CheckBoxSave.Checked == false)` If something is not true then it has to be false use

```
if (CheckBoxSave.Checked) 
{ 
... 
} 
else 
{
...
// checkbox is not checked 
}
```

similar is for `if (testingConnection == true)`

You could also refactor your `LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` method a bit:

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = UserNameTxt.Text;
    passWord = PasswordTxt.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passWord))
    {
        UserNameTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        PasswordTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        UserNameTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        PasswordTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("Du måste ange ett användarnamn och Lösenord!");
        return;
    }
    IsServerConnected();
    if (testingConnection)
    {
        if(CheckBoxSave.Checked)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = UserNameTxt.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserPass = PasswordTxt.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    } 
    else 
    {
        UserNameTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        PasswordTxt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        UserNameTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        PasswordTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("Fel användarnamn eller lösenord");
    }
}
```

This way loginForm.ShowDialog() whill be DailogResult.OK only if login succeeded and userName/password will always be set.

Comment: But i only want to open the loginform if its not any login credentials saved. i also want to be able to not save the credentials and still make the function keep going..

Comment: So call this only if you do not have login credentials saved. I would do it like: `internal void ExecBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { If(!IsLoggedIn())//This should check saved credentials { using(LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm()){ loginForm.ShowDialog(); } if(!sLoggedIn()) return;`

Comment: Now the next problem is that it dont update the settings so it dont find the credentials. but if i close the program and then open it again then it can find my credentials..

Comment: I have tried the Settings.Default.Reload(); but it dont work anyway.. any idea @Pablo notPicasso?

Comment: The question is how and when do you save your credentials. From your code it seems that you save them only if `CheckBoxSave` is checked and `testingConnection` is true. You can see edit to my post and refactoring `LoginBtn_Click` method.

Comment: I tried to add                         DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; but it didnt help..

Comment: I need to make an update so when i can get the latest credentials in IB-Form.